# Generate all available numbers for pattern, shuffle and save to multiple files

Tags: c#, performance, task-parallel-library

I've build simple application that allows me to generate all numbers that have desired length and start with prefix.
For example if I specify `12` as prefix and set desired length to 4 it will generate numbers from `1200` to `1299`.
I'm storing all generated numbers in `List<int>` then using shuffe method from Jon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1287572/965722) I'm saving them in pseudo-random order to files, 200000 records per file.

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<int> _prefixes;
    private List<int> _results;
    private readonly Object _resultsLock = new Object();   

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _prefixes  = new List<int>();
        _results = new List<int>();
        int i = 0;

        foreach (string line in AllPrefixes.Lines.Where(l=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l) && Int32.TryParse(l, out i)))
        {
            _prefixes.Add(i);
        }

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        _prefixes.AsParallel().ForAll(item =>
        {
            string prefix = item.ToString();
            //here I'm determining how many numbers i must generate?
            //can't his be done simpler?
            var count = Convert.ToInt32("1".PadRight(9 - prefix.Count() + 1, '0'));

            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                var res = prefix + j.ToString().PadLeft(9 - prefix.Length, '0');
                lock (_resultsLock)
                {
                    _results.Add(Convert.ToInt32(res));
                }
            }
        });

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("Time elapsed (s): {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    }

    //Can't this be done simpler and also parallel?
    private void SaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string dir = @"C:\TESTS";
        int fileCount = 1;
        var file = Path.Combine(dir, string.Format("{0}.csv", fileCount));
        var sw = new StreamWriter(file, false);

        int i = 0;

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        var rnd = new Random();
        foreach (int res in _results.Shuffle(rnd))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(res);
            i++;
            if (i % 200000 != 0) continue;
            fileCount++;
            sw.Close();
            file = Path.Combine(dir, string.Format("{0}.csv", fileCount));
            sw = new StreamWriter(file, false);
        }
        sw.Close();

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("Time elapsed (s): {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

For 200 prefixes all 9 digits numbers are generated on my PC in about 80-90 seconds, when I add some more prefixes I get `OutOfMemory` exception.

Saving to files takes about 6-8 minutes, probably because I store 200000 results per file and I have more than 100 milion of generated results.

I'd like to optimize this as much as possible, time is priority, but memory usage is most important.

All suggestions are welcome!

---

**First fix (thanks to RobH)** - remove AsParallel

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _prefixes  = new List<int>();
    _results = new List<int>();
    int i = 0;

    foreach (string line in AllPrefixes.Lines.Where(l=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l) && Int32.TryParse(l, out i)))
    {
        _prefixes.Add(i);
    }

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    foreach (var p in _prefixes)
    {
        string prefix = p.ToString();
        var count = Convert.ToInt32("1".PadRight(9 - prefix.Count() + 1, '0'));
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            var res = prefix + j.ToString().PadLeft(9 - prefix.Length, '0');
            _simpleResults.Add(Convert.ToInt32(res));
        }
    }

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine("Time elapsed (s): {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}
```

This decreased time by 40 seconds (almost 50%), from 80-90, to about 40-50 seconds. Thanks!

Comment: Parallel operations with a lock in a tight loop are going to be really really slow. I bet it's faster if you remove the `AsParallel` and get rid of the locking.

Comment: @RobH I'll try that right away.

Comment: @RobH You were right, now it generates same result set in about 40-45 seconds. I'll correct that in my question. What about rest of code? Maybe You could suggest more improvements? :)

Comment: @Heslacher It is a textbox in which I can paste all prefixes as new lines, for example `123`, `1254`, `22456`. So they can be different length.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2):

```
//here I'm determining how many numbers i must generate?
//can't his be done simpler?
var count = Convert.ToInt32("1".PadRight(9 - prefix.Count() + 1, '0'));
```

Yes, I think it can be simpler. You basically want to generate from the minimum value to the maximum value while padding zeros to make sure everything is the same length as `enteredLength - prefixLength`.

I think you would be better off doing something like this:

```
List<string> generatedItems = new List<string>();
int lengthToGenerate = enteredLength - prefix.Length;

for (int i = int.Parse(prefix + new string('0', lengthToGenerate)); i <= int.Parse(prefix + new string('9', lengthToGenerate)); i++)
{
    generatedItems.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Let's take a closer look at this. You'll notice that I save the generated items as a collection of strings. We can do this because they need to be written to a file anyway so it doesn't matter if it's a string or an integer.

```
int i = int.Parse(prefix + new string('0', lengthToGenerate)); i <= int.Parse(prefix + new string('9', lengthToGenerate))
```

This line of code allows us to loop from `0` to `9` or `99` or `999` whatever length we need. In effect this means we can iterate every value inbetween.

Afterwards we create our entire new string by simply calling `.ToString()` on the generated number.

The difference with your code is that it now skips every `Convert.ToInt32()` call and a whole lot of padding.

---

Since it's going to be a bunch of unique values anyway, you might as well use a `HashSet<T>` instead of a `List<T>`.

---

You're constantly locking the result set. It's probably faster to just omit the parallellism altogether since we're not doing *that* much work anyway but if you really want to have it, I would suggest looking into splitting the to-generate dataset beforehand, computing the data and storing it in separate collections and at the end combining those collections. Though that might be slightly overdoing things.

---

Automatically dispose of your `StreamWriter` by using a `using` block:

```
foreach(int res in _results.Shuffle(rnd))
{
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(file, false)
    {
        // Get funky
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Thank You for all those suggestions. as first I've tried using `List<string>` but I got `OutOfMemory` exceptions a lot. I'll try to apply all improvements suggested by You and I'll get back to You. P.S.  You suggested using `Take` to get items I must save it single file, How to use it to save all items? How should I use it in loop?

Comment: Mhhm yeah, I guess that a string will take more memory than an integer. I might consider writing the data to a file sooner so you can let the garbage collector collect those unnecessary strings but that would require a change in the way your application works. The `Take()` suggestion wasn't a good one -- I removed it.

Comment: I don't mind changing my application. It must generate all numbers from given prefixes, shuffle them and save to files, 200 000 records per file. I know how to use StreamWriter in `using` but I must create new file for each group (200 000 records)

Comment: You can just put the `file` reassignment above the `using(StreamWriter)` statement and it will use the new file for each new writer.

Comment: I've edited my question with fix based on Your suggestion. Thank You for that! Only writing results to files are left.

Comment: @Misiu: don't update your question, it makes it confusing for others to read. You can always add an answer to showcase the changes you made in the end or make a new question if you want a follow-up.

Comment: sorry for that. I'm only adding partial fixes. I don't want to add my own answer based on others answers, because I want to give credits to original answers creators.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has been said already (and if I understood the problem correctly), I'd say that you are complicating things too much. Let's think about it (on a single prefix for now):

1. We have a prefix indicated by a string (that has a numeric format alright, but it is a string)
2. We have a max length, let's call it `maxLength`, of the numbers you can consider.
3. The allowed length of the prefix, let's call it `prefixLength`, should be `<= maxLength`
4. We need all the numbers that start with the given prefix and have the given `maxLength`

Given the premises, we could do the following (in pseudo code, similar to C#):

```
List<int> GetAllNumbers(string prefix, int maxLength)
{
    int minNumber = int.Parse(prefix);
    int maxNumber = minNumber + 1;
    int lengthDifference = maxLength - prefix.Length;
    List<int> result = new List<int>();

    for(int i = 0; i < lengthDifference; i++)
    {
        minNumber *= 10;
        maxNumber *= 10;
    }

    for(int i = minNumber; i < maxNumber; i++)
    {
        result.Add(i);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Let's take an example. If we have that `prefix = "15"` and `maxLength = 5` we'd need the numbers from `15000` to `15999`. We just parse `prefix` to `int`, multiply it by 10 for 3 times (length of `prefix` is 2 and `maxLength` is 5) and return the numbers from 15000 to 15999 (`maxNumber` is set to 16000 which is the first value that is not allowed).

In addition, if you just need an `IEnumerable<int>` the previous method would be something like the following:

```
IEnumerable<int> GetAllNumbers(string prefix, int maxLength)
{
    int minNumber = int.Parse(prefix);
    int maxNumber = minNumber + 1;
    int lengthDifference = maxLength - prefix.Length;

    for(int i = 0; i < lengthDifference; i++)
    {
        minNumber *= 10;
        maxNumber *= 10;
    }

    for(int i = minNumber; i < maxNumber; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

The methods are not tested, they are just an idea of how to approach the problem for a single prefix.

In the case of multiple prefixes we could also execute the method in a different thread for each prefix.

Also, I'd suggest you transform `private List<int> _prefixes;` into `private IEnumerable<int> _prefixes;` or, better yet, into `private IEnumerable<string> _prefixes;` (see point 1 and [this page](http://brianreiter.org/2011/01/14/ienumerable-is-lazy-and-thats-cool/) for the reason why). In the last case we could transform:

```
    _prefixes  = new List<int>();

    // other code here

    foreach (string line in AllPrefixes.Lines.Where(l=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l) && Int32.TryParse(l, out i)))
    {
        _prefixes.Add(i);
    }
```

into something like:

```
    _prefixes  = AllPrefixes.Lines.Where(l=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l) && Int32.TryParse(l, out i));
```

After that we just need to do something like:

```
foreach (var prefix in _prefixes)
{
    _results.AddRange(GetAllNumbers(prefix, maxLength));
}
```

and then proceed as you are already doing (randomize the `_results` list and write it in a file, or whatever the case may be).

Let me know if something is unclear.